# Social Multiple Sign On, Android App

Tags: android, facebook, google-plus, im+

Hey i have a probleme implementing an android app:

I want to sign in with facebook, google, simultaneously with multiple account ([IM+](http://plus.im/) like).

I found a solution for facebbok, But nothing with google.

A help with google api is welcome: doc, reference code :)

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use something like this :
https://github.com/PinkelStar/pinkelstar-android-demo